# Debugging pytest unitest in vscode results in AttributError sys has no attribute __breakpointhook__ on exit

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pytest, visual-studio-debugging

I use visual studio code 1.27.2 on Ubuntu 18.04 and Anaconda version 4.5.10 to manage my virtual environments.

I have Anaconda and python extensions installed in vscode.

I made a simple test using a virtual environment in which I only installed pytest and pylint for python 3.6.

If I run this simple script:

```
import pytest

def test_test():
    assert True == True
```

Visual Studio Code run the tests perfectly fine and displays the results in the output console.

If I try to debug this script, however, the test runs and upon exit, I get an AttributeError sys has no attribute __breakpointhook__ and I don't understand why? Am I doing something wrong? Is this a bug with Visual Studio Code debugger or pytest integration?

Stack Trace:

```
File "/home/leerro/anaconda3/envs/py36TF/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main "__main__", mod_spec)
File "/home/leerro/anaconda3/envs/py36TF/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code exec(code, run_globals)
File "/home/leerro/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2018.8.0/pythonFiles/experimental/ptvsd/ptvsd/__main__.py", line 211, in <module> singlesession=args.single_session)
File "/home/leerro/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2018.8.0/pythonFiles/experimental/ptvsd/ptvsd/__main__.py", line 205, in main debug_main(addr, name, kind, *extra, **kwargs)
File "/home/leerro/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2018.8.0/pythonFiles/experimental/ptvsd/ptvsd/_local.py", line 28, in debug_main run_module(address, name, *extra, **kwargs)
File "/home/leerro/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2018.8.0/pythonFiles/experimental/ptvsd/ptvsd/_local.py", line 53, in run_module run(argv, addr, **kwargs)
File "/home/leerro/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2018.8.0/pythonFiles/experimental/ptvsd/ptvsd/_local.py", line 125, in _run _pydevd.main()
File "/home/leerro/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2018.8.0/pythonFiles/experimental/ptvsd/ptvsd/_vendored/pydevd/pydevd.py", line 1743, in main debugger.connect(host, port)
File "/home/leerro/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2018.8.0/pythonFiles/experimental/ptvsd/ptvsd/_vendored/pydevd/pydevd.py", line 1099, in run return self._exec(is_module, entry_point_fn, module_name, file, globals, locals)
File "/home/leerro/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2018.8.0/pythonFiles/experimental/ptvsd/ptvsd/_vendored/pydevd/pydevd.py", line 1123, in _exec runpy._run_module_as_main(module_name, alter_argv=False)
File "/home/leerro/anaconda3/envs/py36TF/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main "__main__", mod_spec)
File "/home/leerro/anaconda3/envs/py36TF/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code exec(code, run_globals)
File "/home/leerro/anaconda3/envs/py36TF/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytest.py", line 77, in <module> raise SystemExit(pytest.main())
File "/home/leerro/anaconda3/envs/py36TF/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_pytest/config/__init__.py", line 67, in main return config.hook.pytest_cmdline_main(config=config)
File "/home/leerro/anaconda3/envs/py36TF/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pluggy/hooks.py", line 258, in __call__ return self._hookexec(self, self._nonwrappers + self._wrappers, kwargs)
File "/home/leerro/anaconda3/envs/py36TF/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pluggy/manager.py", line 67, in _hookexec return self._inner_hookexec(hook, methods, kwargs)
File "/home/leerro/anaconda3/envs/py36TF/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pluggy/manager.py", line 61, in <lambda> firstresult=hook.spec_opts.get('firstresult'),
File "/home/leerro/anaconda3/envs/py36TF/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pluggy/callers.py", line 201, in _multicall return outcome.get_result()
File "/home/leerro/anaconda3/envs/py36TF/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pluggy/callers.py", line 76, in get_result raise ex[1].with_traceback(ex[2])
File "/home/leerro/anaconda3/envs/py36TF/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pluggy/callers.py", line 180, in _multicall res = hook_impl.function(*args)
File "/home/leerro/anaconda3/envs/py36TF/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_pytest/main.py", line 208, in pytest_cmdline_main return wrap_session(config, _main)
File "/home/leerro/anaconda3/envs/py36TF/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_pytest/main.py", line 203, in wrap_session config._ensure_unconfigure()
File "/home/leerro/anaconda3/envs/py36TF/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_pytest/config/__init__.py", line 611, in _ensure_unconfigure fin()
File "/home/leerro/anaconda3/envs/py36TF/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_pytest/debugging.py", line 67, in fin sys.breakpointhook = sys.__breakpointhook__
AttributeError: module 'sys' has no attribute '__breakpointhook__'
```

Workspace Settings:

```
{
    "python.unitTest.pyTestEnabled": true,
    "python.unitTest.unittestEnabled": false,
    "python.unitTest.nosetestsEnabled": false,
    "python.unitTest.autoTestDiscoverOnSaveEnabled": true,
    "python.pythonPath": "/home/gabriel/anaconda3/envs/pytestenv/bin/python"
}
```

I tried running it from a debug session using this configuration in launch.json, but it gives me the same stack trace and error.

```
{
     "name": "Debug Pytest",
     "type": "python",
     "request": "launch",
     "stopOnEntry": false,
     "pythonPath": "${config:python.pythonPath}",
     "module": "pytest",
     "envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env",
     "console": "integratedTerminal",
}
```

I am kind of at lost here and don't know where to search next. Sure I can still debug my code since it is only upon exit that the exception occurs, but I find it troubling and I don't know if it is an issue with Visual Studio Code or with my configurations.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a [bug in ptvsd](https://github.com/Microsoft/ptvsd/issues/766) that will be fixed in its next release which will be included in the next release of the Python extension for VS Code.